# knockout - UI not updating when changing single value of a column in observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following `tbody` in my view:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ListingData">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.ColumnNames -->
              <!-- ko if: $data.FieldName == 'Industry' -->
<td data-bind="event:{ dblclick: function(data, event){ $root.getData(data, event , $parentContext.$index())}}">
    <span data-bind="text: $parent[$data.DisplayName]"></span>
              </td>
              <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

`ListingData` is an observable array which contains data in the form of rows and columns. Below is my `getData` function:

```
getData: function (data, event, index) {

    (viewModel.ListinData()[index])["Industry"]='new value';

}
```

When ever user double clicks on the `Industry` td element, I have to modify the value of `Industry` column in the observable array as shown in the `getData` method above based on the item index which I am able to get using `$parentContext.index()`. Now when I check the `Industry` column value after it is modified by calling the `getData` function using the `firebug` JS debugger, the value is getting modified in the observable array but the changes are not reflected in the UI in the corresponding `td`. Here I have to modify one value of one column and not an entire row, so I cannot use `pop()` and `push()` methods.

How can make the observable array update the UI when a single value in its column is modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableArray()` is only observing which items are in an array. It does not observe every property of every item in an array for changes.

So you would need to change the `Industry` in to an `observable()` and then set it using the function syntax.

```
getData: function (data, event, index) {
    (viewModel.ListingData()[index])["Industry"]('new value');
    // or simply //
    viewModel.ListingData()[index].Industry('new value');
}
```

Comment: how can I change a single property in an observable array to an `observable`? If I replace the array at the given index with a new array, will it refresh the UI?